# Casting in Postgres `where` not working as expected when using `!=`

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have two columns in Postgres that I need to compare in a `where`. The column datatypes, however, are different. One is `text` and the other `int`. I'm trying to do the following:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.profile_image_file_size::int != users.profile_image_s3_file_size::int)
```

This doesn't return any results, although there are thousands of records in the database that have the same number in the two columns with one being stored as `text` and the other an `int`. Using casting with `=` works perfectly:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.profile_image_file_size::int = users.profile_image_s3_file_size::int)
```

This returns the records from the database as expected.

Comment: Perhaps they always have the same value.

Comment: There are thousands of records in the database that do not have the same values. :( This is part of a migration I'm busy with.

Comment: Unless Postgres casts any string to 0, eg. "1560" to 0

Comment: If no values are returned at all I would suspect something is coming up NULL or you would get some results. Try including the value in a select and see what comes back.

Comment: For instance, running `SELECT users.profile_image_file_size, users.profile_image_s3_file_size FROM "users" WHERE (users.profile_image_file_size IS NOT NULL) AND (users.profile_image_s3_file_size IS NULL) LIMIT 10` returns 10 records.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Postgres doesn't cast NULL values. Using the following worked:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.profile_image_file_size::int != COALESCE(users.profile_image_s3_file_size, 0))
```

Comment: More correctly Null never = null and never != null.

select 1 where null!=null
(no rows returned
select 1 where null=null
(no rows returned

Comment: `x = null` and `x != null` evaluate to `null` for all `x` (i.e. they're never true); hence the `coalesce` call. Perhaps you want to look at the [`is distinct from` and `is not distinct from` operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
 select 1 where null!=null
```

(No results returned)

```
 select 1 where null=null
```

(No results returned)

When using any type of NULL (casted or not) you'll never get a true result using = or !=. IS is the only right answer. So you can either replace null with a value (using a function), or use "is null" or "is not null"